# Red and green peppers

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions, singular-vs-plural

You have one red pepper and one green pepper. Would the following phrase be correct to express this?

> Red and green peppers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically yes, but if you said that without context I would assume that there were at least two of each.

More precise phrasings include:

- Peppers: one red, one green.
- Peppers: a red and a green.
- A red pepper and a green pepper.
- A red and a green pepper. (conversational)
- Two peppers: red and green.

For completeness, do not say this:

> A red and green pepper

That would be a single pepper that was both red and green.

Comment: Thank you, DCShnnon. It is a helpful comprehensive list. How about when you have three items, do you use the connector "and" with all the items or only at the end?

Comment: Usually like this: "a red, a green and a yellow pepper."  Or:  "a red pepper, a green pepper and a yellow pepper."

Comment: Thank you, Brian. I meant conversationally. Do you speak as you write?

Comment: @JoeKim I would probably say "a red, a green, and a yellow pepper". If I was writing something somewhat formal, like for school or business, I would probably write what Brian has, or "three peppers: red, green, and yellow".